# Two buttons in form SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring

I want have 2 buttons in my form . one button adding child and another button should create family and go to another template. My controller dont see `@RequestParam String action` I have something like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add Child</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Add Child or Children</p></br>

<form method="post" action="/addChild">
First Name <input type="text" name="first_name"></br>
Second Name <input type="text" name="second_name"></br>
Sex <input type="text" name="sex"></br>
Pesel <input type="text" name="pesel"></br>
<input type="submit" name= "Add child"value="Add child"  ></input>
    <input type="submit" name="Create family" value="Create family"></input>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And controller

```
@PostMapping(value="addChild", params = "Add child")
public String addChild(@RequestParam("first_name") String firstName,
                       @RequestParam("second_name") String secondName,
                       @RequestParam ("sex") String sex,
                       @RequestParam ("pesel") String pesel,
                       @RequestParam String action){

    if(action.equals("Add child")) {
        ChildForm childForm = new ChildForm();
        childForm.setFirstName(firstName);
        childForm.setSecondName(secondName);
        childForm.setSex(sex);
        childForm.setPesel(pesel);
        childService.addChildToDB(childForm);

        return "AddChild";
    }else if(action.equals("Create family")){
        return "basic";
    }
    return "AddChild";
}
```

Comment: You don't have any `input` elements named `action`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `submit` button will execute the action specified in the `<form>` tag. Basically, you added 2 buttons that will execute the same action.

You can create another form element for the second submit button (it doesn't share parameters with the first one):

```
<form method="post" action="/createFamily">
    <input type="submit" name="Create family" value="Create family"></input>
</form>
```

OR

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='/createFamily';" value="Create family" />
```

OR

```
<a href="/createFamily" class="button">Create family</a>
```

Create another entry point in the service, don't mix 2 endpoints together. You are breaking single responsibility design principal and it will hurt you in the future:

```
@PostMapping(value="addChild")
public String addChild(@RequestParam("first_name") String firstName,
                       @RequestParam("second_name") String secondName,
                       @RequestParam ("sex") String sex,
                       @RequestParam ("pesel") String pesel){

        ChildForm childForm = new ChildForm();
        childForm.setFirstName(firstName);
        childForm.setSecondName(secondName);
        childForm.setSex(sex);
        childForm.setPesel(pesel);
        childService.addChildToDB(childForm);

        return "AddChild";
}

@PostMapping(value="createFamily")
public String createFamily(){
       return 'basic';    
}
```